# Actionscript 3: color effects under DisplayObject

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, colors, sprite

I have a DisplayObject (let it be a Sprite).

What I need is to make content under it black-and-white (only within its borders). Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Write a pixel bender filter to do it. :) http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could grab the stage under it, clipped to the rect of the sprite you want to use, desaturize the bitmap (with a colormatrixfilter or the tween code from @chris' answer) and `addChildAt(bitmap, 0)` it inside the sprite as a background.

Then hope that nothing underneath changes because then you'd have to do it all again to reflect those changes into the b/w background.

I have not tried that myself but it might work.

Comment: Clipped bitmap, used ColorMatrixFilter, added Bitmap => works fine, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Download TweenMax (best tweening platform for Flash in my personal opinion).

http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/

Then all you need to do is import it and add the following:

```
import com.greensock.*; 
import com.greensock.easing.*;

TweenMax.to(mc, 1, {colorMatrixFilter:{colorize:0x000000, amount:0.5, saturation:0}});
```

That will change the mc to black and white over the course of 1 second, you could of course change it to 0 for instant black and white.

Comment: It works, but it's not exactly what I need... I need to make b&w everything just under my sprite